# Google Sheet IF + Filter

Tags: google-sheets

So I have this raw data which I need to filter the score of the user based on specific dates

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(Raw!$AF:$AF, Raw!$AG:$AG=$C2, Raw!$AH:$AH=I$1),"0.00")

Raw!$AF:$AF = Score 
Raw!$AG:$AG = Username
Raw!$AH:$AH = Date
```

If error the result will be 0.00, but if the value is >8 it should display 8.00 only.

So if Raw!$AF:$AF = 8.95 it should display 8.00 only. I am having trouble doing that, already tried insterting IF inside the filter then >8,8 but it won't work

Comment: How many rows are returned by the `FILTER`?

Comment: Could you explain `but it won't work`. What was the error message?

Comment: Just a single value of hours. When I use an inside IF it's just shows blank and nothing

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xqM11vlOCiWt

Comment: I add a new column to change the value of Raw!AF

Comment: Your IFERROR is hiding the real error. Don't use it when testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain `IF`:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(IF(Raw!$AF:$AF>8,8,Raw!$AF:$AF), Raw!$AG:$AG=$C2, Raw!$AH:$AH=I$1),"0.00")
```

Or `MIN`:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(FILTER(Raw!$AF:$AF, Raw!$AG:$AG=$C2, Raw!$AH:$AH=I$1),"0.00"),8)
```